# php: stripping unwanted characters

Tags: php

I'm using HTML entities on a string of rich html text, but some characters like Â are still coming through... how can I either force english-only while still preserving html formatting or force them to HTML?

Comment: I think you better deal with non english characters properly and not use entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following piece of code from [phpbuilder](http://phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10315425) seems reasonable. It checks some input ($string) for invalid characters using regex.

```
if(preg_match("@[^a-zA-Z0-9\~`\!\@#$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\'\"\:\;\?\/\>\<\.\,\|]*@", $string) {
    // There are non-english characters....
} else {
    // There are no non-english characters
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $arr_busca = array('á','à','â','ã','ª','Á','À', 
    'Â','Ã', 'é','è','ê','É','È','Ê','í','ì','î','Í', 
    'Ì','Î','ò','ó','ô', 'õ','º','Ó','Ò','Ô','Õ','ú', 
    'ù','û','Ú','Ù','Û','ç','Ç','Ñ','ñ'); 
    $arr_susti = array('a','a','a','a','a','A','A', 
    'A','A','e','e','e','E','E','E','i','i','i','I','I', 
    'I','o','o','o','o','o','O','O','O','O','u','u','u', 
    'U','U','U','c','C','N','n'); 
    $nom_archivo = trim(str_replace($arr_busca, $arr_susti, $nom_archivo)); 
    return $nom_archivo;
```

I got it directly from the php.net [str_replace page](https://www.php.net/str_replace), which is why the variables are in spanish...

As mentioned in the comments, this is an incomplete list of characters to check for, but this is the idea on how to check and replace them. You might want to search for a library.

Comment: That list is horribly incomplete, and I don't think that it's safe to rely on. It doesn't include any of the character used by languages in northern europe such as å, ä, ö and ü.

Comment: Which is why I said I got it directly from the PHP page.

Comment: Yes it is very incomplete, but that is the technology to use to replace the letters with the English equivalent. I'm sure there is an actual library that will do it better.